# C# Selenium How to find a droplist next to a specific text?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a page that contains multiple droplists that have dynamic Id and dynamic position in page with each refresh.

[image]

I want to first find the droplist that corresponds to the label 5 for example and choose specific value, So I want to find the droplist by the Label next to it.

I tried this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Label 5']/following::div[@class='select custom-select custom-select m-l-1']"));
```

But I get "Unable to locate" error.

Edit:
Added droplist HTML code:

```
<tr class="r0">
    <td class="text">
        <p>Label 5
            <br>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="control">
        <label class="accesshide" for="menuq6803:2_sub0">Answer 1</label>
        <select class="select custom-select custom-select m-l-1" id="menuq6803:2_sub0" name="q6803:2_sub0">
            <option value="0">Choose...</option>
            <option value="1">This is answer 1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="2">This is answer 2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Update the question with drop down html code.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal added the code. The "yui_3_17_2_1_1600085484900_118" id , "menuq6803:1_sub0" here and "Answer 1" are dynamic values

Comment: Get  label   parent (td)  and than in td childrends you will find your droplist  ( child[0] = label , child[1] dropList)

Comment: Try this `//p[contains(text(), 'Label 5')]/following::select`.

Comment: you should post more html, in your attempted xpath there is a `span` and `div` but not in the html you posted.

Comment: @Jpsh : you are right.

Comment: using span was a mistake from me as it turned out to be for another unrelated object in the page, but the code you provided worked perfectly for finding the dropdown @DilipMeghwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple XPaths that should work

```
//p[contains(text(),'Label 5')]/following::select
```

or

```
//tr[.//p[contains(text(),'Label 5')]]/td/select
```

The second one is safer because it requires that both the Label and the SELECT are under the same TR.